# Using Hive for real time queries

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, bigdata

First of all I wanted to clarify that I am learning about Hive and Hadoop (and big data in general), so excuse the lack of proper vocabulary.

I am embarking myself in a huge (at least for me) project which requires dealing with enormous quantities of data which I am not use to deal in the past as I always worked mostly with MySQL.

For this project a series of sensors will produce approximately 125.000.000 data points 5 times an hour (15.000.000.000 a day) which is several times more that everything I have ever inserted into every MySQL table combined.

I understand that one approach would be using Hadoop MapReduce and Hive to query and analyze the data.

The problem I am facing is that for what I could learn I understand Hive runs mostly like "cron jobs" and not with real time queries which may take many hours and require a different infrastructure.

I thought of creating MySQL tables based on the results of Hive queries as at most the data which will be needed to be queried in real time would be approximately 1.000.000.000 rows but I was wondering if this is the right way to go or I should look into some other technology.

Is there any technology I should study which is specifically created for real time queries on big data?

Any tip will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a complicated question.  Let's start by addressing the technologies that you mention in your question, and go from there:

1. MySQL: It should be obvious to anyone who has used MySQL (or any other relational DB) that a traditional out-of-the-box installation of MySQL will never support the volumes that you are talking about.  the back of the envelope calculations are enough to tell us that- assuming that your sensor inserts are only 100 bytes, you are talking about 15 billion x 100 bytes = 1.5 trillion bytes or 1.396 terabytes per day.  That's truly big data, especially if you are planning on storing it for more than a day or two.
2. Hive: Hive can certainly handle that kind of data volume (I and many others have done it), but as you point out, you don't get real-time queries.  Every query will be in batch, and if you need fast queries you'll need to pre-aggregate data.

Now that brings us to the real question- what kind of queries do you need to run?  If you need to run arbitrary, real-time queries and can never predict what those queries might be, then you probably need to look towards comparatively expensive, proprietary data stores like Vertica, Greenplum, Microsoft PDW, etc.  These will cost a lot of money, but they and others can handle the load you are talking about.

If on the other hand you can predict with some degree of accuracy the type of queries that will be run, then something like Hive might make sense.  Store the raw data there, and use the batch query capabilities to do the heavy lifting and periodically create aggregated data tables in MySQL or another relational database to support your needs for low-latency queries.

One more alternative is something like HBase.  HBase gives you low-latency access to distributed data, but you lose two critical items that you are probably accustomed to- a query language (HBase doesn't have SQL) and the ability to aggregate data. To do aggregations in HBase, you need to run a MapReduce job, though that job can then go and store it's results back into HBase for low-latency access again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, I really appreciate your time and your knowledge. As you said I would feel more comfortable creating periodically MySQL tables with pre defined queries (I have yet to make sure that will work with the project) I will take a look at HBase which I understand is modeled after Google's BigTable.Is it suited for real-time? I found http://www.hbql.com/ for SQL alike queries. Again THANKS a lot!

Comment: HBase will only work if your queries are lookups or range scans on the key. It is a key-value storage.

Comment: will NoSQL storages such as Mongo and cassandra help here? I suppose they are designed with real-time queries support

Comment: This answer is quite old, and there have been significant new developments in NoSQL storage and query engines since then.  I have not looked into them broadly enough to elaborate on them I'm afraid.